# Vim modules for navigating C++ code base?

Tags: c++, vim, code-navigation

Besides ctags / cscope,

what are good vim plugins for navigating C++ code base?

Ideally, when my cursor is on a variable name, I would like to be able to know:

what is the class of this variable,
what functions can I call on this varaible,
jump to the class of this varaible ...
and do this across multiple namespaces.

What tools do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

You might look into [Eclim](http://eclim.org/), Vim and Eclipse integration. Best of both worlds.